# use Google geocode to return street name and list of house numbers using php

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geocoding

I have a registration form that I would like to fill with data when a user arrives on this section of the form.
The first part of the form asks for the postcode/zip code. On the form load I would like to be able to display a list of house numbers with the street name.

This is what I have to return the data

```
<?php
$postcode = 'DH90ER';
$geourl = file_get_contents("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=$postcode&sensor=true");

$array = json_decode($geourl,TRUE);

print header("Content-type: text/plain");

print_r($array);

?>
```

This works it reruns an array of information that i need except the street name or numbers.
For example if I echo

```
echo $array['results'][0]['address_components'][1]['long_name'];
```

This would echo the Town name. Its messy I know but it works really well.
Is there a way I can get a the street name as postal codes are unique to street names and the number of possible houses?

I've been stuck for a while on this, I will use javascript if it is possible with javascript.

UPDATE to return single house number and street name

```
$geourl = file_get_contents("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=$postcode&sensor=true");

$array = json_decode($geourl,TRUE);

print header("Content-type: text/plain");


$lat = $array['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'];

$lng = $array['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng'];


$add = file_get_contents("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=$lat,$lng");

$add = json_decode($add);
print_r($add);
```

Comment: The response contains bounds as lat/lng. You might create a subsequent request like http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=54.877,-1.69&sensor=true to retrieve street (which is apparently returned as “Newburn Road” for those data.)

Comment: That works OK I can just add a loop in to generate possible other house numbers. It would be good if it returned every house number in that street though

Comment: This feature request should go to Google, not to me :) Though you might call address for boundaries and retrieve/handle _house numbers range_.