# Google get all street numbers via postcode

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps-api-3

I'm using the following google api to return address details which great!
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=M419AT

Outputs:

```
{
"results" : [
  {
     "address_components" : [
        {
           "long_name" : "M41 9AT",
           "short_name" : "M41 9AT",
           "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Stephen Street",
           "short_name" : "Stephen St",
           "types" : [ "route" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Urmston",
           "short_name" : "Urmston",
           "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Manchester",
           "short_name" : "Manchester",
           "types" : [ "postal_town" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Greater Manchester",
           "short_name" : "Greater Manchester",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "England",
           "short_name" : "England",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "United Kingdom",
           "short_name" : "GB",
           "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
        }
     ],
     "formatted_address" : "Stephen St, Urmston, Manchester M41 9AT, UK",
     "geometry" : {
        "bounds" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 53.4485883,
              "lng" : -2.3455666
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 53.4477573,
              "lng" : -2.347262
           }
        },
        "location" : {
           "lat" : 53.4480395,
           "lng" : -2.3461457
        },
        "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
        "viewport" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 53.4495217802915,
              "lng" : -2.345065319708498
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 53.44682381970851,
              "lng" : -2.347763280291502
           }
        }
     },
     "place_id" : "ChIJWySxSBmse0gRnPi3pOSDWvg",
     "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
  }
 ],
 "status" : "OK"
}
```

**BUT** is there away to return all house / street numbers? in a list via postcode search e.g.

1. smith street, town, city
2. smith street, town, city
3. smith street, town, city
4. smith street, town, city
   etc...

I know there is a auto-complete feature on google - but i don't want that - I just want to create a textbox where the user enters their postcode and street numbers are listed.

I'm curl requests to collect this data.

Many thanks

Comment: Your link doesn't work for me, so I cannot see the data you get. This makes your question hard to read. Why not add the data in the question?

Comment: That's odd, its works for me, It just shows an array for address details for that postcode, but it doesn't show individual street numbers.

Comment: Not odd, you're probably logged into Google using Chrome and you're feeling all warm and cuddly while Google learns more and more about you and your business. No, just kidding, thanks for the data.

Comment: haha...you right! think chrome automatically added my api key to the URL

Answer (score 0):

I think Google still doesn't do this. See this question from three years ago:

[use Google geocode to return street name and list of house numbers using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27228768/use-google-geocode-to-return-street-name-and-list-of-house-numbers-using-php)

However, it is possible, for instances on this website:

https://getaddress.io

This returns:

```
{
  "latitude": 53.4482322,
  "longitude": -2.3464489,
  "addresses": [
    "1 Stephen Street, , , , Urmston, Manchester, ",
    "2 Stephen Street, , , , Urmston, Manchester, ",
    "3 Stephen Street, , , , Urmston, Manchester, ",
    "4 Stephen Street, , , , Urmston, Manchester, ",
    "5 Stephen Street, , , , Urmston, Manchester, ",
    "6 Stephen Street, , , , Urmston, Manchester, ",
    "7 Stephen Street, , , , Urmston, Manchester, ",
    "8 Stephen Street, , , , Urmston, Manchester, ",
    "9 Stephen Street, , , , Urmston, Manchester, ",
    "10 Stephen Street, , , , Urmston, Manchester, ",
    "11 Stephen Street, , , , Urmston, Manchester, ",
    "12 Stephen Street, , , , Urmston, Manchester, ",
    "13 Stephen Street, , , , Urmston, Manchester, ",
    "14 Stephen Street, , , , Urmston, Manchester, ",
    "15 Stephen Street, , , , Urmston, Manchester, ",
    "16 Stephen Street, , , , Urmston, Manchester, ",
    "17 Stephen Street, , , , Urmston, Manchester, ",
    "18 Stephen Street, , , , Urmston, Manchester, ",
    "20 Stephen Street, , , , Urmston, Manchester, ",
    "22 Stephen Street, , , , Urmston, Manchester, ",
    "24 Stephen Street, , , , Urmston, Manchester, ",
    "26 Stephen Street, , , , Urmston, Manchester, ",
    "28 Stephen Street, , , , Urmston, Manchester, "
  ]
}
```

And there might be other services that do the same. The Royal Mail also gives you 50 addresses a day:

https://www.poweredbypaf.com

Comment: Thank you for your response...I've seen all those links already..I need to get the address list for free so I need to build my own custom function and not use paid Api's the 1st link you provided was interesting but not sure how he looped through each address

Comment: Information has a value, and providing it costs money, so I don't think you're gonna find this for free. You could also have mentioned, in your question, that you were looking for something that's free, and how many postcodes you wanted to look up, since you've seen the links and you therefore know that these are free below a certain amount. Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask